# Android Studio runs wrong test -- unit test is executing from androidTest package

Tags: android, testing, android-studio-3.0

I have two tests, one unit test and one instrumentation test:
`[...]/src/androidTest/java/com/mydomain/api/ApiClientTest.java`
`[...]/src/test/java/com/mydomain/api/ApiClientTest.java`

Right-clicking on `androidTest/.../ApiClientTest.java` and selecting "Run ApiClientTest" is running the test class in `test/` instead of the one in `androidTest/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by renaming the `androidTest` test class to `ApiClientInstrumentTest.java`

Now that the names aren't duplicated I have no issues.